# retrieve the query with maximum timestamp

Tags: java, algorithm

I have strings which contain query and timestamp separated with "---".
Multiple strings have the same query but with different timestamp. I need to get the query with the maximum timestamp.

The input string is like below:

```
3-13-2018 00:08:07.890---select * from tablename;
3-13-2018 00:08:37.920---select * from tablename;
3-13-2018 00:02:05.880---select * from tablename;
```

Kindly help me with an approach.

Comment: I thought I could split the string and store it in an array. But after that I could not figure out a way to proceed further

Comment: Sounds like a standard parsing problem.
Use a loop to iterate over the input lines.
Then use a string parser with the '---' as a delimiter, and simply map the query string to the timestamp.
If you have an existing mapping of a query - replace the timestamp if it is lower then the one you currently found in your current line iteration.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. But how can I compare this timestamps?. Is there a way to compare with micro seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way to do it.

- Iterate through each string that contains the timestamp.
- Split the string with "---" as a separator (`String#split`)
- Convert the string timestamp from the above step to a `Date` object (`SimpleDateFormat.parse(String);`)
- Compare all the `Date` objects amassed this way and find the max.

Comment: Thanks.Will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the pseudo code, try to build upon this further

```
Timestamp maxTimestamp = null;
for (String s : eachLine) {
    // 1. parse s using `--` delimiter, grab the timestamp token
    // 2. Use java8 API to get Timestamp object from the above token
    // 3. Compare the current timestamp with maxTimestamp
    if (currentTimestamp.after(maxTimestamp) || null == maxTimestamp) 
        maxTimestamp = currentTimestamp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. Much needed help.

Answer (score 0):

try it 
  **SELECT *, MAX(timestamp) FROM `your table name`**